# best approach for realtime notifications

Tags: php, websocket, pusher

first of all: this is a **general** question. I don't have any code yet, I just need your (expert) **opinion**.

Ok, here it goes.

I'm creating a website for buying/selling stuff, something like ebay but then not that big (and for a specific type of products). And I need realtime notifications. Untill now, I used PHP/MySQL + jQuery/AJAX. But I want something better.

If someone buys something, the seller needs to get a notification that something is bought. The notification can (a) be "realtime" (if the seller is online) or (b) delayed and shown when the seller comes online.

I'm familiar with PHP and I've "fooled around" with Pusher. Is this the way to go? Or do I need something like (for example) Ratchet? Or is this just the same? And how should I "create" this?

The way I **think** I should do this is the following:

1. Store every notification in the database
2. If the seller (the channel) is online, push the notification through pusher
3. If the seller (the channel) is offline, fetch all the unseen notifications when he comes online
4. If the notification is seen, update this in the database (or maybe just delete the notification from the database?)

Can someone who has (some) experience with this kind of stuff give me some advice?

Thanks in advance!

PS: sorry for my English (not my native language, I hope you all understand my question)

Answer (score 0):

You could used websockets natively:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

https://caniuse.com/#search=websocket

Notice the libraries mentioned in the first link.

Websockets do use resources on your server (open connections), so this might be one reason to go for a paid solution like https://pusher.com/pricing

I did notice you never really mentioned exactly how quick you want the notifications to appear. Websockets are meant for realtime updates, if anything slower will do, say 5 - 30 seconds, then polling might be easier on the server, if the script that is called is kept to a minimum. You could poll intelligently: Quick in the beginning, slower when the page is open longer. Try to check what the user is doing, is the mouse cursor moving over the page? Then do the updates quickly, otherwise slow them down. Is the user scrolling? Etc.

PS: This is not really a programming problem, as you said in the beginning. It might be considered off-topic, and answering a question like that will seldom be rewarded, or welcomed. Hence the silence.